# parse deploy throwing an error

Tags: python-2.7, parse-platform

I added bunch of js and images file and now when i try to do parse deploy i get this error

```
$ parse deploy
Uploading source files
Error talking to the Parse servers, try again
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 162, in _run_module_as_main
File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
File "/usr/local/bin/parse/__main__.py", line 6, in <module>
File "/usr/local/bin/parse/main.py", line 537, in main
File "/usr/local/bin/parse/main.py", line 159, in handle_deploy
File "/usr/local/bin/parse/parse.py", line 324, in deploy
ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
```

My python version is 2.7 and i saw that none of the files i am uploading has any space character in the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing spaces from the filename worked. So,

```
public/web page.html 
renamed to: 
public/webpage.html
```

See here for more info:
https://www.parse.com/questions/parse-deploy-fails-python-error

(This happened to me due to a conflicted file version created by working on two different machines using Dropbox for syncing. I rm -rf public/* and rebuilt my project and parse deploy worked correctly.)